# Get objects from table

Tags: java

I wrote this function. I am trying to find an object in a table of objects and return a strings table.

```
public Server(wine[] d) {
   this.d=d;
}

public String[] getData(String name) {
   String[] data = new String[2];
   int i=0;         

   while(i < d.length && s != d[i].id)
      i++;

   if (i < d.length) {
      data[0] = d[i].name;
      data[1] = d[i].price;
      return data;
   } 
     else System.out.println(s + " Not Found ");

   data[0] = "error";
   data[1] = "error";
   return data;
 }
```

I got this error

```
getData  invocation: system exception was thrown.
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Cannot marshall null string.
```

I thik the problem is in these two lines:

```
data[0]= d[i].name;
data[1]= d[i].price;
```

Comment: Looks like this error comes from some totally different code that you have not shown. Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: How are you calling `getData`? Is it `getData(null)`? Also, why does `getData` take an unused `String name`?

Comment: Without knowing which lines throw the error we can't help. It's probable that you passed a `null` string to `getData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you want to get the name and price for a type of wine out of an array of wine objects. try this.

```
public String[] getData(String name)
{
    String[] data = new String[2];
    boolean wineFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    {
        if( d[i].name.equals(name) )
        {
        data[0] = name;
        data[1] = d[i].price;
        wineFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (wineFound == true)
        return data;
    else
    {
    data[0] = "error";
    data[1] = "error";
    return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh oh, `d[i].name == name` compares strings with `==`